# Преобразовать числа записанные прописью в их десятичный аналог: "три" -> 3

Tags: python

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы определить такое:

```
Сколько будет три плюс 2?
```

Можно ли как-нибудь из "три" сделать 3?

P.S Вместо "три" может быть и "3", "десять", "10", короче, любое число.

Comment: `сто двадцать пять минус восемьдесят два` - какой ответ должен быть? `125 - 82`; `100, 25 - 80, 2`; `100, 20, 5, -82` ...

Comment: 1-й. 125 - 82. Но я не знаю, как это сделать :с

Comment: @user291959 можно.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, как же?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предложу такой код, который использую сам, но он не работает с окончаниями вроде `тысяча` и `семь тысяч` Вариативность русского языка однако. Взят был c  [английского *SO*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)

```python
def text2int(textnum, numwords={}):
    if not numwords:
      units = [
        "ноль", "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять", "шесть", "семь", "восемь",
        "девять", "десять", "одиннадцать", "двенадцать", "тринадцать", "четырнадцать", "пятнадцать",
        "шестнадцать", "семнадцать", "восемнадцать", "девятнадцать",
      ]

      tens = ["", "", "двадцать", "тридцать", "сорок", "пятьдесят", "шестьдесят", "семьдесят", "восемьдесят", "девяносто"]

      scales = ["сто", "тысяч", "миллион", "миллиард", "триллион"]

      numwords["и"] = (1, 0)
      for idx, word in enumerate(units):    numwords[word] = (1, idx)
      for idx, word in enumerate(tens):     numwords[word] = (1, idx * 10)
      for idx, word in enumerate(scales):   numwords[word] = (10 ** (idx * 3 or 2), 0)

    current = result = 0
    for word in textnum.split():
        if word not in numwords:
          raise Exception("Неверное слово: " + word)

        scale, increment = numwords[word]
        current = current * scale + increment
        if scale > 100:
            result += current
            current = 0

    return result + current

print text2int("семьдесят тысяч пятьдесят три")
>>>70053
```